# Does performance of query improve on increasing text length of index for text fields

Tags: mysql, performance

I wrote a query to search based on a text field column. Right now the performance is very low in retrieving the results. There seems to be an improvement in performance upon applying the index on this text field.

My question is that, will there be any improvement in the performance upon increasing text length of index for text fields example in this below example if I increase from 10 to 15 say.

```
CREATE INDEX test_info_index ON testdoc_db.test_descriptions(test_info(10));
```

Comment: Without knowing what queries you are running, it is impossible to make a judgement.  Your queries may not be using the index now.  Making the key longer might just make a bigger, unused index that has no impact on performance.

Comment: Just a select query. Select * from table where test_info="somestring"; ....but the table contains lot of entries

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question without knowing more.

Firstly, you might want to run an EXPLAIN to see if your index is being used at all, and what its effect is.

Secondly, yes, lengthening the index might improve performance - but only if you have a LOT of entries where the first 10 characters in the text field are identical, and the data is longer than 10 characters.

You might want to look at [full text searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead - it's usually a lot faster for searching long blocks of text.